# No success call for JSONP request if one of the multiple calls fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Here's the problem in an abstract way, I have multiple IPs. I want to figure on which of the IPs the server lies. The server hosts a json file to help with JSONP request.

```
for (index = 0; index < ipArray.length; ++index) {
            var ip = ipArray[index];
            $.ajax({
                url: utils.getJSONPRequestURL(ip),
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {console.log(this.url)}
            });
        }
```

The above function works fine if the IPs are not reachable, it will call the success function which prints the url that succeded. However if one the calls return net::ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED error. I will not get a success callback at all.

Please note that if i remove jsonpCallback option from the ajax request and define

```
window.callback = function(data) {console.log(data)}
```

This will get called in spite of the above mentioned error, however I will not know on which URL did I get this callback from.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification to your ajax function:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: utils.getJSONPRequestURL(ip),
            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {console.log(this.url)}
        }).done(function(){
           console.log("done");
        });
```

The done function should fire regardless of the call's success.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for reply, but unfortunately the done callback doesn't work as well

Comment: Will you try commenting out the 'jsonpCallback' parameter and see what fires?